# Android TextView not refreshing after new Text has been set

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, textview, xamarin.android

I have a `TextView` in a `RelativeLayout` together with a button. When the button is pressed, the `TextView.Text` (corresponds to `setText(string)` in Java I believe) is set to a new value. This new value is not show on the screen. When I press the button second time, the previously set value shows, not the current value. I tried running the code that sets the `TextView.Text` on a UI thread, I have tried to call `Invalidate()` after setting the value but no luck there. When I move the `TextView` outside of the `RelativeView`, the `TextView` gets set correctly and the change is reflected immediately. I have built a test view and activity to test this behaviour isolated from the rest of the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:layout_margin="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/test_layout">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/test_text"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/test_increase"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Add"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/test_increase" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity is in C# (Xamarin) but should be straight forward to create in Java:

```
[Activity(Label = "TestActivity", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class TestActivity : Activity
    {
        Button _testIncrease;
        TextView _testText;
        int _currentIndex = 0;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.test_navigation);

            _testText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.test_text);

            _testIncrease = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.test_increase);
            _testIncrease.Click += (sender, args) =>
            {
                _currentIndex++;
                _testText.Text = _currentIndex.ToString();
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: call [`postInvalidate`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Views.View.PostInvalidate()/) inside the `.Click`?

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion. I have tried that and it wouldn't work. I have seen this working on my device but not in emulator. Any idea why that would be the case? Also, the fact that if I move the `TextView` outside of the `RelativeLayout` it updates without the need for `postInvalidate` is making me uncomfortable about my understanding of the actual issue.

Comment: I ran your code, exactly as posted, in a new Xamarin Android app project and it worked as expected on Google's emulator. So not sure what is going on on your end. Screencast:http://screencast.com/t/lJPcLSgXP7d